# I am using database ref inside a for loop but its not getting data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my function:

```
private void getOrderID() {

    for (int i = 0; i < userID.size(); i++) {
        databaseReference.child(opearatorID).child(userID.get(i)).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    keyStatusRelation.put(childSnapshot.getKey(),childSnapshot.getValue(Order.class).getStatus());
                }
                loadData();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

This fuction gets an error 
because data is not loaded in firebase

```
 public static void loadData() {

    for (int i=0;i<userID.size();i++){
        statusRefrenceLiving.child(userID.get(i)).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Order order = childSnapshot.getValue(Order.class);
                    if(keyStatusRelation.get(childSnapshot.getKey()).equals("0")||keyStatusRelation.get(childSnapshot.getKey()).equals("2")){
                        bookingmList.add(order);
                        bookingrecyclerView.setAdapter(bookingAdapter);

                    }
                    if(keyStatusRelation.get(childSnapshot.getKey()).equals("1")){
                        bookedmList.add(order);
                        bookedrecycleView.setAdapter(bookedAdapter);

                    }
                    if(keyStatusRelation.get(childSnapshot.getKey()).equals("3")){
                        LivingmList.add(order);
                        LivingrecycleView.setAdapter(livingAdapter);

                    }

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is logcat

> Process: com.teepe.teepestaysmasterapp, PID: 6867
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>           at com.teepe.teepestaysmasterapp.MainActivity$4.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:187)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

It's looping and going only to the second line and not entering onDataChange , can any one tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. This means that your main code continues, while the data is being loaded. And then when the data is available, your `onDataChange` gets called.

This means that you can't step into `onDataChange` with a debugger, because the data isn't available yet. If you want to see what happens in `onDataChange` in a debugger, put a breakpoint on the first line in the method, and let the debugger continue. One the data is available, `onDataChange` will be called, and the breakpoint will hit.

Comment: I have edited the question because even if data is loaded later then why is the second func. trying to access it

Comment: That's a completely different problem than you first seemed to describe. Which line is `MainActivity.java:187`? Because that is where you are `get(...)` on a non-existent `Map`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it